# W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring

Tags: java, android

> When my app is running below warning prints after some interval (like 2-3 minutes)

```
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
```

**Device is moto g3**

can anyone have information about why this log is printed ?

Comment: post some code what you think the problem occurred

Comment: When app is launched, that time above log is printed

Comment: I think you are attaching a view somewhere a dialog I presume that was detached.

Comment: Nothing, i added when app launch that time this warning came

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?